# How can i make the "link_click" work without affecting the required field validators?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

To elaborate my question, I have  shopping cart website. Also I have textboxes like username, address, contact etc. All of those has the required field validator. However I also do have the "view profile" and "log out" link button on the page. When I try to clike those links, its not letting me because the required fields are not filled up. Is there any trick I can do with this? Thank you for any answers :)

Here is my code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerName" runat="server" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Customer Name is Required." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerName"
    ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        Phone No:
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerPhoneNo" runat="server" Width="231px" 
            MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Phone Number is required." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerPhoneNo"
            ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        EmailID:
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerEmailID" runat="server" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage=" Email Address is Required." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerEmailID"
            ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
```

and here is my link codes.

```
 protected void link_ViewProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("viewprofile.aspx");
    }

    protected void link_Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Check blog on validationgroup in asp.net validator. This will solve your problem.

Comment: checked it. have read it and it worked. thank you and Godbless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those link button on which you want to run validation add validationgroup attribute. For Example

```
<asp:button id="Button2" 
  text="Validate" 
  causesvalidation="true"
  validationgroup="LocationInfoGroup"
  runat="Server" />
```

Also add validationgroup attribute in RequiredFieldValidator

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Phone Number is required." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerPhoneNo"
validationgroup="LocationInfoGroup"
            ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the link on how i managed to solve it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.140).aspx. credit to @Tonny